# Twitter, how to get user's oauth secret?

Tags: twitter, oauth

My callback url is only receiving oauth_acccess_token and oauth_bridge_code. How do I get the secret from these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually supplied to you. Go to your app settings at https://dev.twitter.com/

You will see your oAuth Secret Key

Comment: Not mine, the users, the php library's im using ask for user_token and user_secret.

Comment: No, its you that has to supply your own. In this case you can consider Consumer key = User token and Consumer secret = User Secret. Consumer = User

Comment: There's a consumer key, a consumer secret, a user token and a user secret. I want the user token and user secret. The callback url is receiving an access token after they authorize connection with my app. How do I get the user token/user secret from this? I already know what my consumer key/secret is, i've successfully used the API for my own account, but now i'm trying to use the api with other peoples twitter accounts.

Comment: To rephrase, how do I get the access token secret from the access token? The callback url does not receive it after authorization at https://oauth.twitter.com/2/authorize.

Comment: Ted, the access token secret is supplied to you. Please check your application detail at https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ You cannot get the access token secret from the access token. Also please what library are you using?

Comment: Please check out https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth/blob/master/examples/tweet.php , if I have 1000 users my website needs to tweet for, which of those 4 fields would remain constant (not change, i.e. belongs to me) ?

Comment: All the 4 fields would remain constant. Those fields belong to you.

Comment: So there's an API I have to use to tweet for other users which takes the access token? can you provide a link please? thanks

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api#tweets says "Updates the authenticating user's status, also known as tweeting." Those 4 fields determine which user I authenticate as. Yet if they always remain the same.. how do I tweet on my website's users accounts they've given me permission to 'connect' to?

Comment: Ok. Useful links http://natelyman.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=89:twitter-oauth-tutorial&catid=34:php&Itemid=64

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/oauth/authenticate

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/oauth/authorize

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/access_token

But I don't think you need all those since there already are numerous libraries http://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fdocs%2Ftwitter-libraries&ei=9OV4TtjfBcPS4QTNhfGiDA&usg=AFQjCNGdHhUBSwZzR8ghBr8QRmB7kXqxcA